# Pushing content below a position:fixed top nav so it's visible

Tags: html, css

This problem arises when you are using a `position:fixed` top nav bar: Since the nav bar is out of the document flow, the initial content that you put after it will be hidden by the nav bar itself.  This fiddle shows my solution which uses an extra spacer div and `padding-top`:

http://jsfiddle.net/MFwJT/

#### html

```
<div class="fixednav">some nav stuff</div>
<div class="navspacer"></div>
main content which should not be covered by nav
```

#### css

```
.fixednav { position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 30px; background: #999 }
.navspacer { padding-top: 30px; } /* This works */
```

#### 2 questions

1. Is there a better solution?
2. If you change `padding-top` to `margin-top`, the nav bar behaves as if the spacer came *before* it rather than after it.  I'd like to know why this happens.

To clarify question 2, `margin-top` produces this:

[image: Imgur]

whereas `padding-top` produces this (the correct behavior):

[image: Imgur]

Comment: is `position:fixed` mandatory to be `fixednav` class or you just need a placement like it with other attributes also at your disposal???

Comment: It's mandatory.  In any case, the top nav needs to "stick" to the top of the page even when you scroll down, and I want a pure CSS solution, so I believe `position:fixed` is the only way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better solution

IMHO, better solution would be to avoid a fake spacer div `navspacer` and instead, go with the `span` as you can easily achieve your target with a single div, using `line-height` and without a fake `div`

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MFwJT/2/)

**CSS**

```
.fixednav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999;
    line-height:90px; /*this is the key here*/
}
.fixednav > span {
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    line-height:30px;/*this is the key here*/
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixednav"> 
    <span>some nav stuff</span>
    main content which should not be covered by nav
</div>
```

**Question 2**

> If you change padding-top to margin-top, the nav bar behaves as if the spacer came before it rather than after it. I'd like to know why this happens.

when you give the `padding-top: 30px;`, it is applied to the inside of the content area, making the whole div height (30px + if anything is in content), [check this demo to see it](http://jsfiddle.net/MFwJT/4/)

when you give `margin-top: 30px;`, it is applied to the outside of the content, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MFwJT/6/)  and the contents overlap as `FIXED` position divs do not follow the document flow but the viewport flow!!

Comment: Indeed, I much prefer this solution, although I would place the `</div>` directly after the `</span>`  Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  Do you know the answer to the 2nd question I asked?

Comment: i answered the 1st question....updating for 2nd question...give me 2 mins please!! :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution to your questions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .fixednav {
      position:fixed;
      top: 0;      
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: #999
    }

    .main-contents {
      margin-top: 30px; 
    }
  </style>  
  <title>this is a test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fixednav">some nav stuff</div>
  <div class="main-contents">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the first question, you can fix it by putting all your main contents in a <div> and place the div under your main nav bar.

For your second question, it can be solved by simply adding `top: 0;` to the style

the mdn states that

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned relative to its initial containing block, which is the viewport in the case of visual media. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

Which means you ought to definite its position. Otherwise the browser has no idea how to place the element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you fixed the position of the fixednav but not the navspacer. When you do this, the fixednav and navspacer are on the same line since one is fixed and not the other. When you add padding to the navspacer, it pushes away the fixednav from it. When you add margin-top:30px; it moves the fixednav and navspacer together. To fix this, add a fixed position to the navspacer and add the content to the fixed navspacer:

```
/*html*/    
<div class="fixednav">some nav stuff</div>
<div class="navspacer">main content which should not be covered by nav</div>

/*css*/ 
.fixednav { position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 30px; background: #999 }
.navspacer { position:fixed; margin-top: 30px; }
```

This will give you the correct behavior you are looking for. 
Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/4vAgZ/

Also, this picture should help you with the padding vs. margin thing.
http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/ae09140c.png

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gree, I appreciate this response but that solution has a problem: you are applying the margin-top to what happens to be the first content element on the page.  But that content element will be different on each page (imagine a site wide nav), so it's not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div for spacing like youtube does. 
Here i made an example wich uses javascript to listen on window resizes and adjusts the spacer if necessary.
But you can also use this [jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/) for every single div.

```js
    //initial adjustment
    $(function () { $('#topSpacer').height($('#fixedtop').height()); });

    //adjustment on every resize event        
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#topSpacer').height($('#fixedtop').height());
        console.log("<div>" +$('#topSpacer').height() + "</div>");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topSpacer"></div>

<div>
  Does anyone overlay me?
</div>

    <div id="fixedtop" style="position:fixed; top: 0px;">
        Top navbar elements Page0000000000000 Page11111111111111 Page2222222222222
    </div>

<div>
    Another relative element
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in nav with is-fixed-top i.e.:

`<nav class="navbar is-fixed-top">`

then add below class to your body

`<body class="has-navbar-fixed-top">`

this will take care of appropriate spacing.
You can also add the class to HTML which will give you some additional space from top of page.

The class is basically adding a padding top of 3.25rem either to body or html.